# ImageView с закруглёнными углами

Tags: android

Хочу сделать Image View, с закруглёнными углами, нашёл вот такой код

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:elevation="10dp">

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/drawImage1"
    android:layout_width="380dp"
    android:layout_height="165dp"
    android:background="#757575"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.516"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.114" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Мне нужно как то добавить Card View  в проект, нашёл этот код который надо вписать в build gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.+'
}
```

В итоге мне пишет что не знает никакого android.support.cardview-v7.21.+
Помогите добавить Card View

Comment: Ээээм.... Ныне что бы добавить какую либо библию от Гугл хватит просто кинуть элемент на экран. Скорее всего он их не нашёл так как это очень старые либы. Все уже давно пользуются AndroidX

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны указывать конкретную версию библиотеки.

Например:

```
com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0
```

**Обратите внимание:** [пакеты Support Library устарели](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages). Задумайтесь о миграции на `androidx`

Для `androidx` можно добавить эту версию:

```
androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду использовать androidx